# Prevent scrollbar from jumping down when viewing a list box?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a chat room in windows forms and have a listbox that displays all the messages recieved, ofcourse I have the chatbox set to automatically scroll to the bottom when a new item is sent. However, if the user is looking at old messages and a new item is sent, the scroll bar immediately jumps to the bottom.

I was thinking that I could do something like:

```
if(scrollBarPosition != scrollBarBottom) doNotJumpToBottom
```

except I can't seem to find any scroll bar position variable.
This is my jump to the bottom code:

```
chatListBox.TopIndex = chatListBox.Items.Count - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add a checkBox near your listBox to allow or prevent the automatism.

For example, if you decide that if the checkBox is checked, then the listBox follows the incoming events going to the bottom, you can do this:

```
    listBox1.Items.Add(newItem); // this is where a new entry comes
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        chatListBox.TopIndex = chatListBox.Items.Count - 1;
    }
```

So (in that example), if the box is unchecked, the user can freely scroll up or down where he wants, and resume to see the incoming items by checking the box.